# Get Items from list without id field query in Batch

Tags: sharepoint-online, caml-query, batch

I have a SPO list with 30000 list items. I need to query the items in the list based on some of the `single line of text` type fields. Below is the code to do that

```
public List<Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItem> GetListItemsBatch(string listName, string query = "")
{
    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (SecurityProtocolType)48 | (SecurityProtocolType)192 | (SecurityProtocolType)768 | (SecurityProtocolType)3072;
    List listResult = _context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(listName);
    CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery { ViewXml = query };
    
    //Creating a single buffer for storing all the ListItems
    List<Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItem> lstListItemCollection = new List<Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItem>();

    do
    {
        Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItemCollection result = listResult.GetItems(camlQuery);
        _context.Load(result);
        _context.ExecuteQuery();

        //Adding the current set of ListItems in our single buffer
        lstListItemCollection.AddRange(result);

        //Reset the current pagination info
        camlQuery.ListItemCollectionPosition = result.ListItemCollectionPosition;

    } while (camlQuery.ListItemCollectionPosition != null);

    return lstListItemCollection;
}

string query = $"<View Scope='RecursiveAll'>" +
                $"<Query>" +
                $"<Where>" +
                $"<And>" +
                $"<Eq>" +
                $"<FieldRef Name='ContactNumber'/>" +
                $"<Value Type='Text'>{item.ContactNumber}</Value>" +
                $"</Eq>" +
                $"<Eq>" +
                $"<FieldRef Name='Email' />" +
                $"<Value Type='Text'>{item.Email}</Value>" +
                $"</Eq>" +
                $"<Eq>" +
                $"<FieldRef Name='ProjectCode' />" +
                $"<Value Type='Text'>{item.ProjectCode}</Value>" +
                $"</Eq>" +
                $"<Eq>" +
                $"<FieldRef Name='ProjectSubCode' />" +
                $"<Value Type='Text'>{item.ProjectSubCode}</Value>" +
                $"</Eq>" +
                $"</And>" +
                $"</Where>" +
                $"</Query>" +
                $"<RowLimit Paged='TRUE'>30</RowLimit>" +
                $"</View>";

 var spoItems = spo.GetListItemsBatch(listName, query);
```

I get the "The attempted operation is prohibited because it exceeds the list view threshold" or "Cannot complete this action. Please try again." issue when i try to run with the above query combination.
It works if i replace the conditions with `ID` field and remove `and`. Problem is i need it running without providing the ID field in query.

Answer (score 0):

The workaround what i tried was, got rid of the `where` parameters. Since it's a batch call i get all the items from the list. Finaly i did LINQ for the same conditions on the returned items in the list.